# Positive and negative variation of signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is question 3.1.7 from Folland's Real Analysis

> Suppose $\nu$ is a signed measure on $(X,M)$ with $E \in M$. Show that $\nu^+(E) = \sup \left\lbrace \nu(F) : E\in M, F \subset E \right\rbrace$ and $\nu^-(E) = -\inf \left\lbrace \nu(F) : E\in M, F \subset E \right\rbrace$

Here's what I've done:

For any $F \subset E$, by the Jordan Decomposition, there exists a unique positive measure $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$. By monotonicity, we know $\nu^+(F) \leq \nu^+(E)$ and $\nu^-(F) \leq \nu^-(E)$. So we have:

$$\nu(F) = \nu^+(F) - \nu^-(F) \leq \nu^+(F) \leq \nu^+(E)$$

Similarly, $\nu(F) \geq -\nu^-(E)$

Since $F \subset E$ was arbitrary we get:

$\nu^+(E) \geq \sup \left\lbrace \nu(F) : E\in M, F \subset E \right\rbrace$ and -$\nu^-(E) \leq \inf \left\lbrace \nu(F) : E\in M, F \subset E \right\rbrace$

However, I'm having problems showing the reverse inequalities to conclude equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jordan decomposition of $\mu$ is usually given in terms of a Hahn decomposition of the space $X$: there exist measurable sets $P$ and $N$ with the property that $P \cap N = \emptyset$, $P \cup N = X$, $E \subset P$ implies $\nu(E) \ge 0$ and $E \subset N$ implies $\nu(E) \le 0$.

Then by definition $\nu^+(E) = \nu(E \cap P)$ and $\nu^-(E) = - \nu(E \cap N)$.

Thus $\nu^+(E) = \nu(E \cap P) \le \sup\{\nu(F) : F\in \mathcal M, \ F \subset E\}$ since $E \cap P \in \mathcal M$ and $E \cap P \subset E$. A similar argument works for $\nu^-(E)$.